# Is there anything in the rules that say a familiar can attune to magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, familiars, attunement

**Is there anything in the rules that say a familiar can attune to magic items?**

I've seen lots of questions about if familiars can attune to items and the community seems to agree on that they can. However, my DM will not allow this without seeing a specific ruling that they can, as it is not enough for them to simply **not** have a ruling **against** it.

Has Jeremy Crawford put out anything that confirms familiar can attune to and use magic items? Did I miss something in the rules? Or is it simply, nothing says they can't?

Comment: There's nothing in the rules that say a dog CAN'T play baksetball!

Comment: @DavidCoffron the DM states they aren't smart enough to attune and says even if it could, it can't use any magic items like a tentacle rod because the rod makes an attack roll. (Even though the familiar is activating a magic item, not making an attack roll)